# React Hover Styling

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Forgive me if this has been asked before, I've gone through loads of answers and failing to get this working. Basically I'm just after adding a background color when hovering over my `<p>` element. I don't want to use JavaScript hover events, I want to use just CSS stylings.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work and what the common solution is? I've tried so many combinations, eg `:hover {. &:hover {, ':hover': {, '&:hover': {` etc.

Thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Thing = styled.p`
  background: none;
  width:200px;
  padding:20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: auto;
  ':hover': {
    background: red;
    textDecoration: underline;
  }
`;

export const BorderButton = ({text}) => (
  <Thing>
    {text}
  </Thing>
);
```

Comment: The key have to be '&:hover'

Comment: As stated above, &:hover also does not work, with or without the single quotes.

Comment: I don't think you need the `''` surrounding `&:hover`.

Comment: @MartinCrawley, Does this help you?? https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-bultz

Comment: The above link does work, but not when I copy that styling into my own code.

Comment: just remove '' from :hover it will work

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: you have style that ovveride you styled component could you post some global css used there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had another styling on the page where this component was being rendered. Removing that style seems to have fixed it, though I don't understand why.

```
<Styles>
    <div className="main">
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
      <BorderButton />
    </div>
  </Styles>
```

to

```
    <div className="main">
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
      <BorderButton />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `:hover` without ''(quotes). That is CSS part, you need to write Pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`:hover` is the correct accessor/selector.

```
const Thing = styled.p`
  color: black;
  background: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: auto;

  :hover {
    background: red;
    text-decoration: underline; // also use correct css naming!
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit pedantic-lumiere-zzoof]

Comment: I can see that this works, but it doesn't work when I copy this styling into my component for some reason. I'm so confused!

Comment: @MartinCrawley can you copy *your* code into a running sandbox and reproduce the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The hover should be like  &:hover { ... } not a text as you mentioned ,

Also be sure (inspect mode ) that this value isn't overridden at other globale css style

```
const Thing = styled.p`
  color: black;
  background: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: auto;
  &:hover {
    background: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`;
```